# Todo list using Class

Tags: javascript

So I am learning JS classes and I am facing already an issue at start, I can't add any todo to my list. I can't find solution what I'm doing wrong.
My code:

```html
<input type="text" id="addTodo" />
<button onClick="TodoAddCommand">
Add
</button>
```

```js
let Todos = [
{
 id: 0,
 content: "test",
 done: false
}

]
class TodoAddCommand {
    constructor(e) {
  this.event = e;
  }
  
  execute() {
  const todo = {
    id: Todos.lenght,
    content: this.event.data,
    done: false,
  }
  
  Todos.push(todo);
  console.logo(Todos);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`TodoAddCommand` is a class; you are trying to call it like a function.

Instead, create a new instance of `TodoAddCommand` and pass the event to the constructor, then call `execute()`:

```js
let Todos = [{
    id: 0,
    content: "test",
    done: false
  }

]
class TodoAddCommand {
  constructor(e) {
    this.event = e;
  }

  execute() {
    const todo = {
      id: Todos.lenght,
      content: this.event.data,
      done: false,
    }

    Todos.push(todo);
    console.log(Todos);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="addTodo" />
<button onClick="new TodoAddCommand(event).execute()">
Add
</button>
```